# Cannot append jquery element to newly wrapped element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to wrap a div around an already existing div, and then append to that newly created parent div.

```
// create parent
var $top = $('<div id="top">top</div>');

// wrap it around child
$('#middle').wrap($top);

// append to new parent
$top.append('<div id="bottom">bottom</div>');
```

Here is the jsfiddle showing that the append doesn't work....

http://jsfiddle.net/3WRDc/2/

Here's what it should look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/3WRDc/1/

Any ideas why such a simple sequence of operations isn't working? I understand I can easily start with the parent and append the two children, but in this case I need to do it this particular way.

Comment: From the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) (emphasis mine): *"The `.wrap()` function can take any string or object that could be passed to the `$()` factory function to specify a DOM structure. [...] **A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements** in the set of matched elements. This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes."*

Comment: An alternative approach http://jsfiddle.net/3WRDc/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) clones the wrapper you specify. The documentation says (emphasis mine):

> The `.wrap()` function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the `$()` factory function to specify a DOM structure. This
>   structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only
>   one inmost element. **A copy of this structure will be wrapped around
>   each of the elements in the set of matched elements.** This method
>   returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

You have to reselect `$top`:

```
$("#top").append('<div id="bottom">bottom</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/3WRDc/4/

Use `.insertAfter()`

```
var $top = $('<div id="top">top</div>');

$('#middle').wrap($top);

$('<div id="bottom">bottom</div>').insertAfter('#middle');
```